# Joining two 2D-arrays in numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I have a (1000, 784) 2D array and a (8000, 784) 2D array, and been trying to concatentate them to get a (9000, 784) 2D array.

I've tried:

```
np.concatenate((A, B))
np.vstack((A, B))
np.hstack((A, B))
```

but none of them work. Would anyone be able to help me out?

Comment: What happens when you try `vstack`?

Comment: Both `np.concatenate((A,B))` and `np.vstack((A,B))` should work.  Please show the exact code that you tried, and the complete error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand where your problem comes from...:

```
>>> a = np.zeros((1000,784))
>>> b = np.zeros((8000,784))
>>> c = np.concatenate((a,b))
>>> c.shape
(9000, 784)
>>>
```